# Copying Windows Registry Changes in Multi-stage Builds

Tags: windows, docker, registry, docker-multi-stage-build

I'd like to use multi-stage builds more in Windows images, but a limitation I've hit is that many programs - particularly those for components like Visual Studio and related tools - alter the Windows Registry during their installation process.

Are there any ways to dump the registry changes made while building one stage to a `*.reg` file so that you could then apply those changes in a later build stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I jumped the gun a bit with this; Windows doesn't support BuildKit and thus you cannot use multi-stage builds with Windows images at the moment anyway.

Should that change and I figure out how to use it with registry-altering installers, I'll update.

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/issues/34